# Django custom user model: IntegrityError: null value in column "is_superuser" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-custom-user

I am trying to create a custom user model in Django and thereafter create RESTAPI as per django-rest-auth provides.

CustomUserModel and CustomUSerManager are defined as-

```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import (
      BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
  )

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
use_in_migrations = True

def create_user(self, email, name, phone_no, user_android_id, user_fcm_token,
                user_social_flag, user_fb_id, user_android_app_version, password=None):
    user = self.model(
        email = self.normalize_email(email),
        phone_no = phone_no,
        password=password,
        user_android_id = user_android_id,
        user_fcm_token = user_fcm_token,
        user_social_flag = user_social_flag,
        user_fb_id = user_fb_id,
        user_android_app_version = user_android_app_version,
        name = name,
    )
    # user.is_staff = False
    # user.is_superuser = True
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_staffuser(self, email, name, phone_no, user_android_id, user_fcm_token,
                user_social_flag, user_fb_id, user_android_app_version, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        phone_no=phone_no,
        user_android_id=user_android_id,
        user_fcm_token=user_fcm_token,
        user_social_flag=user_social_flag,
        user_fb_id=user_fb_id,
        user_android_app_version=user_android_app_version,
        name=name,
    )
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_admin = False
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, name, phone_no, user_android_id, user_fcm_token,
                user_social_flag, user_fb_id, user_android_app_version, password):
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        phone_no=phone_no,
        user_android_id=user_android_id,
        user_fcm_token=user_fcm_token,
        user_social_flag=user_social_flag,
        user_fb_id=user_fb_id,
        user_android_app_version=user_android_app_version,
        name=name,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
   objects = UserManager()

   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
   created_at = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   phone_no = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   user_android_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   user_fcm_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   user_social_flag = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
   user_fb_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
   user_android_app_version = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

   def __str__(self):  
      return self.email
```

Custom View File:

```
from rest_auth.registration.views import RegisterView
from app.models import User

class CustomRegisterView(RegisterView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

In settings.py file I have set:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.User'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True


 REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
   "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": 
  "app.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer",
 }
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": 
  "app.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer",
 }
```

I have set the urls in url file.

```
re_path(r'^registration/$', views.CustomRegisterView.as_view())
```

When I run the /registration/ url, and fill all the details I get error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "is_superuser" violates not-null constraint
>   DETAIL:  Failing row contains (8, pbkdf2_sha256$120000$VpGItoUPHoJ9$yBQB2PqRDiqd4SQ2cDZX/wzaV3yFSf..., null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, custom@user.com, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1:**

While checking the database records, I found that only email, password, and last_login fields are only inserted and rest all are null. What could be reason?

**UPDATE 2:**

CustomRegisterSerializer class:-

```
   class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField()
    phone_no = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_android_id = serializers.CharField()
    user_fcm_token = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    user_social_flag = serializers.IntegerField()
    user_fb_id = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    user_android_app_version = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'phone_no', 'user_android_id', 'user_fcm_token',
                  'user_social_flag', 'user_fb_id', 'user_android_app_version')

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()

        return {
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'phone_no': self.validated_data.get('phone_no'),
            'name': self.validated_data.get('name'),
            'user_android_id': self.validated_data.get('user_android_id'),
            'user_fcm_token': self.validated_data.get('user_fcm_token'),
            'user_social_flag': self.validated_data.get('user_social_flag'),
            'user_fb_id': self.validated_data.get('user_fb_id'),
            'user_android_app_version': self.validated_data.get('user_android_app_version'),

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `create_user` you've commented `is_staff` and `is_superuser`. Uncomment and set them to `False`.

EDIT:

About the fields not getting into database - `is_staff` and `is_superuser` are not defined in your user model and are also not defined in the `AbstractBaseUser`. Which is strange, because in this case you shouldn't have gotten that exception in the first place.

Are you just now starting your project or have you ran migrations before swapping the user model?
If you've started with the default user model from Django, you'll need some more work to do. Hopefully you don't have any real users yet and you could do it quick.
Take a careful look at the [topic in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Great. +1. It helped. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing, Can I customize RegisterAPIView and LoginAPIView response, so that the same is used for android and ios.

Comment: While checking the database records, I found that only email, password, and last_login fields are only inserted and rest all are null. What could be reason?

Comment: Okay, I have updated the model, and now custom fields got saved.
Another Point here is: 
When we register using API, it returns the a key value. But I want to customize the response with additional fields such as primary key value and a result_flag which will be either 0 or 1. How can we achieve this?

Comment: I think this is for separate question.

Comment: As suggested, I have created a new question. Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53319843/modify-response-from-django-rest-api-using-customusermodel-extending-default-use